# why I can not use tenserflow and Keras in my Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I successfully installed tenserflow and Keras but when I import them in Jupyter notebook it say

```
ModuleNotFoundError
```

but in my VScode is working! what is problem?

I use Mac I installed them in terminal like this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow

pip install tensorflow

pip  install keras -U
```

Then I did this in the terminal:

`conda create -n keras python=3.7.6`

```
conda activate keras

conda install keras
```

Comment: How did you install those packages?

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: please see edited question

Comment: go to anaconda prompt, activate your environment, then install these

Comment: I should search how to access anaconda prompt. I will try thanks

Comment: @NicolasGervais I created a new environment , now should I installed in terminal again? same as before?

Comment: Make sure your current environment has jupyter installed. When you create a new environment, if you don't install jupyter and try to use it, it will run jupyter installed in other environments (which may not have keras/tensorflow installed)

Comment: @BashirKazimi please check the edit. still I get the same error

Comment: @elham in your environment, you should also install jupyter (and/or ipython) again. 

`conda install -c anaconda jupyter`
and
`conda install -c anaconda ipython`
otherwise, it will use jupyter or ipython from another environment which does not include keras/tensorflow